# Derivation of geometric mean?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

It is given the geometric mean:

$$f(x) =(\prod_{i=1}^{k}x_i)^{1/k}$$ on $R_{++}$

The first derivation is a chain rule:
$f'(x)=\frac{1}{k}(\prod_{i=1}^{k}x_i)^{\frac{1}{k}-1} \cdot (\text{inner derivation})$

How do I do the inner derivation: $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{k}x_i\right)$?

Comment: What is $\;x\;$ and how do you differentiate with resepct to it the first expression?

Comment: the best will be to take the logarithm on both sides

Comment: @Peter Then your question makes no sense, as what are then the $\;x_i$ 's ??

Comment: $x_i$ is a scalar > 0

Comment: Differentiate in elementwise: $$\frac{d}{dx_i} \left(\prod_{j=1}^{k}x_j\right) = \left(\prod_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \ne i}}^{k}x_j\right)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be a multivariable ($k$-variable) function:
$$f(x)=f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_k)=\left(\prod_{i=1}^k x_i \right)^{1/k}.$$
You can take a partial derivative:
$$\dfrac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_{i}}=\frac{1}{k}\cdot x_i^{\frac{1}{k}-1} \left( \prod_{j=1, j\ne i}^k x_j \right)^{1/k}.$$

For example: $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1x_2x_3)^{1/3}:$
$$f_{x_1}=\frac13 x_1^{1/3-1}\cdot x_2^{1/3}x_3^{1/3}$$

Comment: Isn't there a product missing after der fraction 1/k?

Comment: No, nothing is missing. Can you be more specific?